# How do I make the CMD close after this bat file runs

Tags: batch-file

I have this bat

```
start C:\Users\Techno\Downloads\AudioVisualizer.exe
"C:\Program Files\Rainmeter\Rainmeter.exe" !LoadLayout "Music"
exit
```

How do I make it close after its done running
It closed before I added the load layout, but now it doesn't
I know its simple, but it would be really helpful
(latest versions of windows 10)

Comment: Technically the CMD does close after the bat file runs. The issue is that you don't want it to! The batch file was written to exit after `Rainmeter.exe` has completed. When you close `Rainmeter.exe` your batch file will end. Use the `start` command with an empty window title on lline `2` if you want the `exit` command to run immediately after `Rainmeter.exe` is started.

Answer (score 0):

Windows NT4 and newer.

How to write cmd scripts that do not stop a batch file from closing w/o closing the programs opened by your commands:

```
start "" "%UserProfile%\Downloads\AudioVisualizer.exe.lnk"
start "" "%ProgramFiles%\Rainmeter\Rainmeter.exe.lnk" !LoadLayout "Music"
```

According to [Mofi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3074564/mofi) these programs are not required to be started from shortcuts to prevent the batch file from being paused. As I am not familiar with audiovisualizer and rainmeter and knowing that some programs must be started from shortcuts to prevent the batch file from being paused, I have started them from shortcuts.